# Angular Variables rendering undefined with Flask/Jinja

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, jinja2

For seemingly no reason my angular $scope variable is not rendering in the browser. My whole project has been working just fine until I created this page today. All other pages still work as expected. I've deleted all my code down to just the variable itself with the following code and its still rendering as [undefined].

I'm using python/flask to serve up the application with the jinja templating engine and therefore have changed the interpolation characters for angular so they don't conflict with the same characters in jinja:

```
var zues = angular.module('zues', []);
zues.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{{[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}}');
}]);
```

Controller:

```
zues.controller('test', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.test123 = "testing123";
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="zues" ng-controller="test">

{{[ test123 ]}}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/js/zues.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/js/Controllers/test.js"></script>
```

python/flask route:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import flask
application = Flask(__name__)
@application.route("/test")
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='127.0.0.1', reloader_type='stat', debug=True)
```

This renders in the browser simply as:

[Undefined]

I would have expected it to render:

testing123

Anything simple that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: angular code wise there is no challenge. looks like some issue due to routing...plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/sYKKMARS3ytTL9NN4Fqx?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, that's what's so weird, the routing doesn't get any more basic then what I provided and it works for all my other routes. I even stripped it out to run entirely as its own application and cleared all my browser history/ensured there were no caching problems and I'm still getting undefined. I'm completely baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My interpolation characters that I picked for angular were too closely related to the characters that Jinja uses by default. Jinja was taking {{[ test123 ]}} and interpreting the square brackets as plain text and then trying to find a variable test123 within my python script that didn't exist.

This didn't seem to break on the rest of the project because the angular variables I used in my html templates in the rest of the project were always bound to something else and therefore being watched by the digest loop whereas in this scenario it would only have been interpolated once.

I changed the interpolation characters to be {[{ test123 }]} so that Jinja never catches it and only angular does.

Answer (score 0):

A few quick changes should help.

1) Get rid of the interpolate provider. *You won't need this code if you complete 2 & 3 below.*

2) Remove the close bracket **]** when you close the controller definition

- Yours: **}]);**
- Mine: **});**

3) Add **{{ '** before the set of curly braces and after **' }}**

example/ {{ '{{someVariable + "" + anotherVariable}}' }}